# identify this plant

Tags: species-identification, botany

location: trabzon (turkey) can seen in rural areas, in woods and in some gardens.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the American South will call that Poke Salad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like pokeweed (*Phytolacca americana*):

[image]

Source: https://nature.mdc.mo.gov/discover-nature/field-guide/pokeweed

[image]

Source: http://ribbonsandlines.blogspot.com/2012/09/september-at-cape-may-point-nj.html

Per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phytolacca_americana):

> Pokeweed is native to eastern North America, the Midwest, and the Gulf
>   Coast, with more scattered populations in the far West. It is also
>   naturalized in parts of Europe and Asia.